# Why does for_each + lambda trigger -Waggregate-return warning?

Tags: c++, c++11

When trying the following example with gcc and the `-Waggregate-return` flag the warning: `function call has aggregate value` triggers:

```
struct Element {
// ... stuff ...
}

Container<Element> elements(10);
for_each(begin(elements),end(elements),[](Element& e){

// ... modify elements ...

});
```

As far as I could find out, the `-Waggregate-return` flag "Warns if any functions that return structures or unions are defined or called", because, if I understood correctly, you could potentially overflow the stack by returning a large enough object.

However, `for_each` returns <strike>the type of</strike> the lambda, whose type is `void`. Why does it trigger the warning? What have I missed? How can I improve my code?

Comment: The return type of your for_each is not void. It is the lambda expression.

Comment: So if for_each returns the lambda, and the lambda returns void, what triggers the warning?

Comment: @GonzaloBG: `for_each` returning the lambda, I guess. Technically it's not an aggregate, but the warning seems to be for "structures or unions" rather than aggregates, and presumably that includes classes in C++.

Comment: @gnzlbg: I am not very familiar with the gcc. But I assume that the compiler will create a struct for your lambda and this will be  returned by the for_each thus the warning.

Comment: @mkaes thanks! that seems to be exactly what is happening! 
Sadly, this makes the warning pretty much useless if your code contains lots of for_each + lambda's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does it trigger the warning?

Presumably, the warning is triggered by returning anything of class or union type. Lambdas have class type, and `for_each` returns its function argument, so that will trigger the warning.

It's also possible that the iterator type returned by `begin(elements)` and `end(elements)` might trigger the warning, depending on how the `Container` type implements iterators.

> How can I improve my code?

I'd disable that warning; it's not really compatible with idiomatic C++, since it's very common to return small class objects from a function. It would also be triggered by, for example, `std::map::insert()`, which returns a pair, and many other standard library functions.

Comment: Sorry, but you are incorrect. For containers `begin(c)` is equivalent to `c.begin()`.

Comment: @PierreBdR: That's correct, but I didn't say anything about `begin(c)`.