# Confusion in regards to purpose/behavior of -Waggregate-return?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, warnings, gcc-warning

While looking at the [GCC's warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options),  I came across *-Waggregate-return*.

> **-Waggregate-return**
>   Warn if any functions that return structures or unions are defined or called. (In languages where you can return an array, this also elicits a warning.)

---

**small example that elicits the warning:**

```
class foo{};
foo f(void){return foo{};}
int main(){}
```

> $ g++ -std=c++0x -Waggregate-return -o main main.cpp
>   main.cpp: In function ‘foo f()’:
>   main.cpp:2:5: warning: function returns an aggregate [-Waggregate-return]

---

**another small example that does not elicit the warning:**

```
#include <string>
std::string f(void){return "test";}
int main(){}
```

---

What is the benefit gained from using -Waggregate-return?
Why would someone want to be warned about this?
Also, isn't std::string a class?- why arn't I warned about the 'returned aggregate' in the second example?

Comment: `std::string` is a class; but not an aggregate. (It has a non trivial constructor)

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11473099/1284631

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the comments made by @AlokSave, here is a later edit of the answer:

Three are two possible explanations for this compiler flag. Since the documentation about it is scarce, it is somewhat unclear what its original meaning is, but there are, mainly, two possible explanations:

1) Warning the user about returning an aggregate object make him aware that the stack could overflow if the aggregate object (which is allocated on the stack) is returned.

2) Apparently, some old C compiler did not support returning aggrregates (you had to return a pointer).

Which of the two is the best one, it is hard for me to judge. However, more relevant information about this flag may be found at the following links:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/644271-aggregate-return-warnings

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2012-09/msg00006.html

Quoting from the latter link:

> > > > In the GNU apps I'm familiar with (Emacs, coreutils, ...)
> > > >         we simply disable -Waggregate-return.  It a completely
> > > >         anachronistic warning, since its motivation was to
> > > >         support backwards compatibility with C compilers that
> > > >         did not allow returning structures.  Those compilers
> > > >         are long dead and are no longer of practical concern.

Comment: I don't see why this warning would make sense then; if this made sense then a warning for any aggregate on the stack would make sense; and I don't see that.

Comment: In C++ a smart compiler would usually apply RVO or NRVO, So this definitely doesn't apply.

Comment: @BillyONeal It is only of interest if you compile for a platform (embedded) where stack is really small.

Comment: @AlokSave The "smart compiler" could simply lack heap on the platform of interest.

Comment: AFAIK, RVO or NRVO is not dependent on presence or absence of heap.

Comment: @AlokSave yes, you are right. but, as the edits show, returning aggregates is not always featured by the compiler.

Comment: I am sorry to say what I see above is When your initial argument was questioned you provided a counter argument which was completely irrelevant and when that was pointed you completely ignore the incorrectness and point to a new argument.Please be concrete in what you say and whenever you do, so with adequate evidences not mere here says.

Comment: @AlokSave I updated my answer according to your comments. Thank you very much for contributing at putting the discussion on the right track.

Answer (score 5):

Aggregates are defined in the C and C++ standards. The C version says (C99 6.2.5 Types/20-21):

> A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of member objects
>   (and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array), each of which has an optionally
>   specified name and possibly distinct type.
>
> [...]
>
> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and
>   structure types are collectively called aggregate types.

The C++ version says (N3485 8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]/1):

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Your second example (with `std::string`) doesn't trigger the warning because `std::string` has a user-provided constructor; and has private data members.

It is my suspicion that this warning exists because it is considered poor style to return an aggregate in C; passing an out pointer is preferred in that language instead. I don't think it applies to C++ as much. But I can't confirm this with any data.

Comment: *"because it is considered poor style to return an aggregate in C; passing an out pointer is preferred in that language instead"*, What is the basis of this assumption? Any references?

Comment: @Alok: No, I explicitly said I have no references in the answer. I've had C programmers yell at me for doing this in C; presumably because C people think/thought it was inefficient to return an aggregate (and incur copying). But as I said, I can't back that up with data; it is merely a suspicion.

Comment: in K&R C it was not possible to return a struct by value, these people yelling at you probably haven't picked up a reference since 1975. Or maybe are on a platform where the ABI doesn't support this and the compiler is non-conforming (I have encountered that)