# trying to silence -Waggregate-return only in a macro for g++ - buggy compiler?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, compiler-bug

using g++ and compiling with `-Waggregate-return`

```
#define DOCTEST_CHECK(expr)                                      \
    do {                                                         \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push");                          \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Waggregate-return\"");\
        if(Result failed = (ExpressionDecomposer() << expr))     \
            printf("%s\n", failed.m_decomposition.c_str());      \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop");                           \
    } while(false)

DOCTEST_CHECK(true == false); // produces warnings
```

but the unrolled by hand version does not produce any warnings:

```
do {                                                                                           
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push");                                                            
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Waggregate-return\"");                                  
    if(Result failed = (ExpressionDecomposer() << true == false))     
        printf("%s\n", failed.m_decomposition.c_str());                                        
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop");                                                             
} while(false);
```

Shouldn't the behavior be the same?

I don't think the `Result` and `ExpressionDecomposer` types matter - just classes.

I'm trying to get expression decomposition working like [here](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest/blob/master/include/lest/lest_decompose.hpp) (things have been renamed a bit).

**EDIT:** >> [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ovPOUzOh3k53NAXI) << is a live demo of the problem using the lest library

My question is: why? how can I be warning free in the first case using the macro?  I cannot afford silencing the warning globally.

Comment: I know this does not answer the question, but `-Waggregate-return` seems rather pedantic and should be ignored, especially in C++ where returning by value is perfectly normal. You can have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016993/confusion-in-regards-to-purpose-behavior-of-waggregate-return).

Comment: I vaguely recall GCC having issues with pragmas in macros; you might want to search their bugzilla.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I would never use that warning for personal code but the library I'm writing is supposed to be completely warning free even on the most aggressive levels (i suffer from perfectionalism)... Also this warning is not in ```-Wall``` or ```-Wextra``` for good reason...

Comment: Quite strange, but this seems to be gcc's behavior. I reproduced it in a much simpler program, with gcc 4.8.2. Compiling with gcc fails, but preprocessing with `gcc -E` and compiling the result succeeds. Maybe a quote from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) is relevant - `To be safe, you are probably best keeping it out of directives other than ‘#define’, and putting it on a line of its own.` - when merging lines with `\\` the pragmas are all in one line.

Comment: Maybe a GCC bug, indeed. See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2016-01/msg04482.html) or [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2016-01/msg00788.html), and maybe others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These bugs look relevant:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55578
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69543

So it might have to do with line number comparisons, or some similar issue within the parser, and it might be fixed in some future version.

Comment: wow that seems pretty general... so far I've silenced only clang warnings with ```_Pragma``` and it works fine there... weird that gcc wouldn't have this working properly for so long

Comment: @onqtam it will work fine outside of a macro, and according to the first bug repory, also in C. Gcc bugs get fixed based on the interest someone has in fixing the bug; a bit of publicity doesn't hurt but there are much older unresolved bugs. Warning bugs are not usually consideref critical, afaik.

Comment: @onqtam by the way, you do need to parenthesize `expr` in that macro (where it is used, not in the prototype.)

Comment: I don't think so - If I pass ```true == false``` I want the ```<<``` operator of my ExpressionDecomposer class to capture the 'true' and then to have it's comparison operators called (they have lower precedence than the shift) with the false (thats how I capture the values of the left and right side of the comparison)

Comment: @onqtam: in that case, I would suggest using two or three arguments. The way it is written is bound to be the source of obscure bugs.

Comment: but then there will be no universal macro for comparisons - there will have to be a ```check_equal``` and a ```check_greater``` and etc. (all with 2 arguments - left and right). Catch and lest (testing frameworks) use such universal macros with expression decomposition. I suppose it is a trade-off for usability.

Comment: @onqtam with 3 args you can do check(arg, ==, val).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105495/discussion-between-onqtam-and-rici).

Answer (score -1):

You could try :

```
#define DOCTEST_CHECK(expr)                                      \
do {                                                         \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push");                          \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Waggregate-return\"");\
    if(Result failed = (ExpressionDecomposer() << (expr)))     \
        printf("%s\n", failed.m_decomposition.c_str());      \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop");                           \
} while(false)
```