# A lot of warnings when compiling date library

Tags: c++, date

The [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library is very useful but you can see a lot of warnings after compiling a simple example that uses date library.
for example:

```
#include "date.h"
int main() {
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << weekday{July/4/2001} << '\n';
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++ -c -Waggregate-return main.cpp

warning: function call has aggregate value [-Waggregate-return]...
```

Comment: Can you show us the warnings?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: yes, compile without errors but with a lot of warnings.

Comment: Show your warnings?  The one in your post is due to syntax of your weekday and date, without  casts or data  conversion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016993/confusion-in-regards-to-purpose-behavior-of-waggregate-return

Comment: and what is the reason you compile with `-Waggregate-return`? it is a pretty obscure (and useless) flag that triggers warnings for a valid C++ code.

Comment: If you ask the compiler to issue useless warnings about perfectly valid and idiomatic C++ code, don't be surprised when it issues useless warnings about perfectly valid and idiomatic C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of your compiler, C++11 (or later) mode might not be active, so try adding `-std=gnu++0x` at least. Also you code needs `#include <iostream>` added.

Answer (score 1):

To fix these warnings you should remove the flag `-Waggregate-return` from your compile string. This flag causes warnings for valid code.

Note that you also need `#include <iostream>`, and for older versions of g++ , `-std=c++14` or a similar flag.