# Why do some GCC warning flags not belong to the C++ language and yet work in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

I was exploring warnings offered by GCC using the `gcc -Q --help=warning` syntax. (See [3.2 Options Controlling the Kind of Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) for more details on that.)

What occurred to me is that many (109 out of 250 with GCC version 6.4.1) warnings are not classified as C++. By that I mean they will not show up when doing a restricted query `gcc -Q --help=warning,c++`. (Out of curiosity, 81 warnings are classified as neither C++ nor C.)

Yet, at least some of those warnings do work in C++. As an example take `-Waggregate-return`. (See it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jATG7C).)

The `-Waggregate-return` is disabled by default and I do know it is probably of little use anyway (see [Confusion in regards to purpose/behavior of -Waggregate-return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14016993/422489)). However, it is just an example, maybe there are some useful flags in those 109 of the same case.

So, why do some GCC warning flags not belong to the C++ language and yet work in C++? What is the rule here?

Comment: Meanwhile GCC has a variety of [front ends](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/frontends.html) (supported languages) with probably different requirements of warnings. I assume that there are warnings (built in) for other languages which are generated inside (say on AST processing level) and may occur for C++ as well although they are originally not intended for this language. But, it's just my guess... (Another guess could be it's just a weakness you found (worth to be reported) but I've too much respect concerning the power to which gcc has evolved meanwhile.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Well, this does seem possible. Although this particular warning (`-Waggregate-return`) as described in [Confusion in regards to purpose/behavior of -Waggregate-return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14016993/422489) seems to be related to C and C++. And yet it shows in neither of them! But maybe the description in linked question is not right...

Comment: I wonder how this question meets the guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @nicomp Fully reproducible. You can even check this online at Compiler Explorer: [all warnings for 6.4](https://godbolt.org/z/zWPTQ6), [C++ warnings for 6.4](https://godbolt.org/z/-yJwU1), [C warnings for 6.4](https://godbolt.org/z/k4-q50), [common warnings for 6.4](https://godbolt.org/z/ZUnIE4) (the last one inspired by answer from Vladislav Ivanishin). What bothers you here about the particular guideline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [the answer from Vladislav Ivanishin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56598949/422489), mainly the concept of "common" flags, I have done split of warning messages from the GCC I'm using (6.4.1):

1. [common](https://godbolt.org/z/6kM5Qh) - 58
2. [C++](https://godbolt.org/z/VaSQQs) - 141
3. [C](https://godbolt.org/z/Lw99Qq) - 133
4. [Objective C](https://godbolt.org/z/j7u-55) - 135
5. [Objective C++](https://godbolt.org/z/hG5HJk) - 141
6. [Fortran](https://godbolt.org/z/FMIpnG) - 36
7. [Ada](https://godbolt.org/z/1gh4hk) - 2
8. [Go](https://godbolt.org/z/jc6b-2) - 2
9. [Java](https://godbolt.org/z/f17l1L) - 5

[Overall](https://godbolt.org/z/RsaqUz) there are 250 messages and all are covered by one or more from the above languages. However, I'm not sure whether this is a complete list of supported languages - I don't know how to check which languages are supported by an arbitrary version of GCC.

The `-Waggregate-return` from the question belongs to the "common" category which is why it is produced for the C++ language as well.

Comment: _I don't know how to check which languages are supported by an arbitrary version of GCC._ It depends on the configuration options and can be viewed with 
`gcc -v |& grep -o -- '--enable-languages[^ ]*'` (bash). I have `c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++` for my GCC 8.3.0 installed from Arch Linux official repos (Java got removed, LTO is not really a language -- that's an implementation detail -- neither is `common`).

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin It seems more complicated than that... My own compiler has `--enable-languages=c,c++` while Compiler Explorer has [`--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran`](https://godbolt.org/z/bUlWIf). At the same time, warnings query show what I have listed above. (But entering some random text in the `gcc -Q --help=warning,<language>` does show error message, so it doesn't accept anything.)

Comment: Furthermore, I have uncovered another issue. If in the query I enter C++ specific flags to have the full picture of my own build status I'm constantly getting warnings like: `cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wnon-virtual-dtor’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C` and the option is not included in the result (unlike others). Even when checking C++ flags. Using `-x c++` didn't help either.

Comment: Yeah, option handling code is independent of the language front-ends; it does not seem to be affected by `--enable-languages`. 
As for `cc1: warning...`, `-x c++` not hepling the situation looks suspicious (wrong).  Probably you are invoking `gcc` where `g++` would be more appropriate. It is unclear why `cc1` compiler proper would be executed the instead of `cc1plus` though. If that's an issue for you, consider asking another question with a [mcve].

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin Finally I made another question for the language perspective problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753102/how-to-query-gcc-warnings-for-c.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in either documentation

```
   --help={class|[^]qualifier}[,...]
       Print (on the standard output) a description of the command-line options understood by the compiler that fit into all specified classes and qualifiers.  These are the
       supported classes:
       ...

       language
           Display the options supported for language, where language is the name of one of the languages supported in this version of GCC.
```

or implementation (I think, it's the latter.)  So go ahead and file a bug if you like. Please be sure to post a link to the problem report here.

Specifically, you don't see any *Common* e.g. language-independent options that are marked with the `CL_COMMON` flag. You do see options that apply to multiple languages, but not all, however (e.g. if they have both `CL_C` and `CL_CXX` flags; `CL_COMMON` is a separate flag whose value is not composed of values of individual language flags).

The code responsible for that is around `gcc/opts.c:1360`:

```
print_filtered_help (unsigned int include_flags,
                    unsigned int exclude_flags,
                    unsigned int any_flags,
                    unsigned int columns,
                    struct gcc_options *opts,
                    unsigned int lang_mask)
                    unsigned int lang_mask)
  ...

  if (include_flags == 0
      || ((option->flags & include_flags) != include_flags))
    {
      if ((option->flags & any_flags) == 0)
        continue;
    }
```

(the caller passes 0 for `any_flags`, so the inner check always succeeds; it's not the point here.)

Comment: The idea of "common" flags was inspiring! I tried to use `common` as language: [`gcc -Q --help=warning,common`](https://godbolt.org/z/ZUnIE4) and got 58 warnings (amongst them the `-Waggregate-return`). At the moment I cannot investigate it further. But I will try to report this as a bug after checking how trunk version behaves (I assume the 6.4 which I have to use will not be corrected anyway).

Comment: I've checked this on a fairly recent trunk (so the latest release is definitely affected). `--help=warning,common` -- hm, interesting observation. This leaves me with a question whether all this is intentional (common vs. C++ warnings). But the manual implies it isn't, so something should be corrected here.

Comment: I have made my own answer where I have summed up "the research" inspired by your mention of the "common" language.