# How to query GCC warnings for C++?

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

GCC allows querying available warning flags specific for C++ language with the syntax:

```
g++ -Q --help=warning,c++
```

Adding warning flags to the call includes them in the result:

```
g++ -Wall -Q --help=warning,c++
```

However, it seems the call is done from the C point of view and I don't know how to do it from the C++ point of view. If the call includes C++-only warning, like:

```
g++ -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Q --help=warning,c++
```

the output contains a message:

```
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wnon-virtual-dtor’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
```

and still shows the warning as disabled:

```
  -Wnon-virtual-dtor                    [disabled]
```

Note, that this happens regardless of whether the call is done using `g++` or `gcc`.

The same with C-only `-Wbad-function-cast` behaves in an expected way:

```
gcc -Wbad-function-cast -Q --help=warning,c
```

There is no extra message and reported warning status changes between `[disabled]` and `[enabled]`. Again, regardless of whether `g++` or `gcc` is used.

I'm using GCC version 7.3.0. Although the issue seems to apply to many if not all versions. [It can be observed through Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/iSZVhh).

So, is there a way to do this query with respect to given language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your observations are correct.

Probably this is not the intended behavior, and if you care about this feature, then I suggest reporting it upstream.

Note that this works, however:

```
touch 1.cc
g++ -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Q --help=warning,c++ 1.cc
```

I.e. if there's an input file with a proper extension, then the correct compiler proper executable is invoked: `cc1plus`, not `cc1`. The latter is the default if no input files are present. I did some quick debugging, and here's how that happens:

```
// gcc.c:
driver::do_spec_on_infiles () const
{
  ...
  for (i = 0; (int) i < n_infiles; i++)
    {
      ...
      /* Figure out which compiler from the file's suffix.  */

      input_file_compiler
        = lookup_compiler (infiles[i].name, input_filename_length,
                           infiles[i].language);

      if (input_file_compiler)
        {
          ...
              value = do_spec (input_file_compiler->spec);
```

And `input_file_compiler` at that point is the C compiler, because

```
p n_infiles
$9 = 1
(gdb) p infiles[0]
$10 = {name = 0x4cbfb0 "help-dummy", language = 0x4cbfae "c", incompiler = 0x58a920, compiled = false, preprocessed = false}
```

Here's how the dummy file got created (function `process_command` in the same file):

```
  if (n_infiles == 0
      && (print_subprocess_help || print_help_list || print_version))
    {
      /* Create a dummy input file, so that we can pass
         the help option on to the various sub-processes.  */
      add_infile ("help-dummy", "c");
    }
```

Comment: I have filed a bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91011.

Comment: BTW, the dummy source file trick doesn't work with my 7.3.0. Judging by [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) it doesn't work with any version up to and including current top 9.1. It works only on the trunk version. Also, the need to have an existing file makes it somewhat imperfect workaround.

Comment: @AdamBadura _"Also, the need to have an existing file makes it somewhat imperfect workaround."_ — As another workaround you can invoke the specific language frontend (`cc1plus`) directly. I think, `gcc --print-file-name cc1plus` should be a portable way to get the path to the executable. _"I have filed a bug:..."_ — Great! I think, we should continue the discussion there to keep it in one place.